# Ksoap2 parser xml data

Tags: android, xml-parsing, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I have used Ksoap2 to connect to this .NET web service and i get a xml response when i enter the users id. I only want to see two tags callTitle and callDescription. I don't need the rest and want to see in text not surround with xml code. can some one please help? I can't find tutorial online.

```
public class AndroidWebService extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetHelpDeskCalls";
    private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static String METHOD_NAME = "GetHelpDeskCalls";
    static final String URL = "https:/192.2344.123:8080/Service1.asmx";

    Button getData;
    EditText userID;
    TextView data;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.helpdesk);

        getData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        userID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtFar);
        data = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        Thread nT = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                getData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,
                                METHOD_NAME);

                        request.addProperty("userID", userID.getText()
                                .toString());




                        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                                SoapEnvelope.VER11);

                        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                        envelope.dotNet = true;
                        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                                URL);

                        try {

                            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
                            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                            final String results = androidHttpTransport.responseDump
                                    .toString();

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {

                                    data.setText(results.toString());
                                }

                            });

                        } catch (Exception e) {

                            data.setText("Error" + e);

                        }

                    }

                });

            }

        };
        nT.start();
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should parse your XML with the help of xml pull parser

Following code will guide you for doing so

```
MyXmlPullParser objMyXmlPullParser = new MyXmlPullParser(context);
                        List<Map<String , String>> list = objMyXmlPullParser.readXml("Xml respose put here", "Table");



public class MyXmlPullParser 
{
    Context _context ;

    public MyXmlPullParser(Context _context)
    {
        this._context = _context ;
    }

    public List<Map<String , String>> readXml(String XmlString , String ParentTag)
    {
        Map<String , String > map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        List<Map<String , String >> list = new ArrayList<Map<String , String >>();

        try 
        {
            String Tag = "" ;
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

            xpp.setInput(new StringReader (XmlString));
            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

            while (true) 
            {
                if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) 
                {
                    Tag = xpp.getName();
                } 
                else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) 
                {
                    Tag = "" ;
                    if(xpp.getName().equals(ParentTag))
                    {   
                        list.add(map);
                        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    }
                }
                else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) 
                {
                    String text = xpp.getText();
                    if(!Tag.equals("") && !Tag.equals(ParentTag)) 
                    {
                        map.put(Tag, text);
                    }
                }
                else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) 
                {
                    System.out.println("End document");
                    break ;
                }
                eventType = xpp.next();
            }
        }

        catch (XmlPullParserException e) 
        {
            Log.e("xml reader" , "error in parsing  xml");
            return null ;
        }
        catch (IOException e)  
        {
            Log.e("xml reader" , "error in IO in xml");
            return null ;
        }
        return list ;
    }
```

Hope it may helps you

Comment: do i make a new class for the xml parsing then call it in the Activity?

Comment: yes you can make a new class for parsing data with passing your arguments in its constructor.

Comment: sorry to bother you i just stared android development so im not good at it could u show me how to use the xml parser code on my code